Metapost dashed evenly option affects lines in TeX labels -- a bug?
Consider this MWE and its output (TeX Live 2023) -- is it a bug?
beginfig(1)
drawoptions(dashed evenly);
draw btex $\sqrt{22222} \displaystyle {1 \over 22222}$ etex;
endfig;
end



How do you compile?

@mickep I compile as described in §3.2 of my guide to Drawing-with-Metaspost.

I am not sure if this is a bug or a "feature" -- but I am amazed that no-one has noticed it before.
It relates to the way that plain Metapost handles the pictures created by btex ... etex.   The newer luamplib library deals with TeX pictures quite differently and does not have the same bug / feature.
As an additional example, consider this table, familiar from p.246 of the TeXBook.
picture T; T = btex 
\def\BC{\hbox to2em{B.C.\hss}}%
\def\AD{\hbox to2em{A.D.\hss}}%
\vbox{\offinterlineskip
\hrule
\halign{&\vrule#&\strut\quad\hfil#\quad\cr
height2pt&\omit&&\omit&\cr
&Year\hfil&&World Population&\cr
height2pt&\omit&&\omit&\cr
\noalign{\hrule}
height2pt&\omit&&\omit&\cr
&8000\BC&&5,000,000&\cr
&50\AD&&200,000,000&\cr
&1650\AD&&500,000,000&\cr
&1850\AD&&1,000,000,000&\cr
&1945\AD&&2,300,000,000&\cr
&1980\AD&&4,400,000,000&\cr
height2pt&\omit&&\omit&\cr}
\hrule} etex;

if you save this as table.mp and then compile this file with plain mpost
prologues := 3;
outputtemplate := "%j.eps";
input table
beginfig(1)
draw T dashed evenly;
endfig;
end

You will get an .eps file that looks like this when converted.

But if you compile this equivalent file with lualatex
\documentclass[border=5mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{luamplib}
\begin{document}
\begin{mplibcode}
input table
beginfig(1)
draw T dashed evenly;
endfig;
\end{mplibcode}
\end{document}

You will see that luamplib ignores the dashed evenly part.  Which is probably the better behaviour.

The general rule appears to be the plain mpost applies the current dash pattern to the drawing, but that luamplib does not.  With the table example here, it is not really clear which is the "correct" behaviour, but I agree that the OP example with dashes in a long sqrt sign and a long fraction bar looks horrible and wrong.
I think it might be worth raising this on the mailing list.
As a work around, I suggest that you either take care not to apply a dash pattern when you draw a <picture> created with btex ... etex, or switch to compiling your MP drawings with luamplib.
Finally I observe that

plain mpost will also apply the currently selected pen to the lines in the text <picture>, but that luamplib ignores it.

both mpost and luamplib will apply color to a text <picture>.


